# warning can't open/read file: check file path/integrity

Tags: python, opencv, path

```
images_per_class = 80
fixed_size       = tuple((500, 500))
train_path       = "dataset/train"

train_labels = os.listdir(train_path)
for training_name in train_labels:
dir = os.path.join(train_path, training_name)
current_label = training_name
   for x in range(1,images_per_class+1):
    # get the image file name
    file = dir + "/" + str(x) + ".jpg"

    # read the image and resize it to a fixed-size
    image = cv2.imread(file)
    image = cv2.resize(image, fixed_size)
```

when i run this code it appeare this error

```
error: OpenCV(4.5.5) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\resize.cpp:4052: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !ssize.empty() in function 'cv::resize'
```

and this warning `[ WARN:0@19.045] global D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgcodecs\src\loadsave.cpp (239) cv::findDecoder imread_('dataset/train\Apple/1.jpg'): can't open/read file: check file path/integrity`

i dont have probleme with installation of opencv because i use it before andwith another code it fonctionne any help please

Comment: please check that the file actually exists: `assert os.path.exists(file)` and also *look* in the directory

Comment: The best advice I've had all day. For some reason Python 3.10.1 is inconsistent with ` \\` and `\\\` on my Windows 10 machine. Some folders/files okay with single. Others need double.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> file = dir + "/" + str(x) + ".jpg"

try to replace this line with :

> ```
> file = dir + "\" + str(x) + ".jpg"
> ```

the / not correct

the correct is \

Comment: a backslash in a regular string literal will escape the following character. this answer contains a **syntax error**. -- opencv/windows is usually tolerant of a mixture of forward and backward slashes in paths. I wouldn't bet on slashes being the issue. -- I _would_ bet on the issue here being that the **file doesn't actually exist**

Comment: its doesnt work

Comment: I use the same syntax with another folder its works but when I change it appears this problem I don't know  why and where is it the problem

Comment: i try to verifie if the file exist it seem doosnt exist                          dataset/train/Apple/1.jpg is not exist 
False

Comment: @awatif try to put your file in the correct path as the code , also make sure that the image extension is the same as the code , if your image is blabla.jpg or blabla.png !!! , in the code put the correct type of the image .

Answer (score 5):

Dears, for me the issue was related to filename extension. I put the extension .JPEG whereas the actual extension was .jpg. Correcting the extension cleared the warning. thanks

Comment: same here I used png instead of jpeg

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that the file name does not contain any special characters, OpenCV seems to be quite sensitive here.

For me the problem was that it contained some umlauts (ä, ö, ü).

Answer (score 1):

You can add below lines before initializing file_name:

```
import os
os.chdir(folder_address_which_contain_your_file)
```

it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Recently I have faced the same issue, the problem was the file was not exist there. I realise file names could also be a problem.[image]

Answer (score 0):

for me, my file path have '\n' in the end. use os.path.exist check, not exist

Answer (score 0):

in my case it was the filename extension that caused problems. Check whether your png/img/bmp is a png/img/bmp or something else ;)

Answer (score 0):

Check if such a file really exists. If it gives an error, put it at the same address as the image or the file, for example:
the location of your file is C:\Desktop with this name polarbear.jpg. The location of the file where you write the code is C:\Desktop\Files\Python
Let it be called kod.py. The code will give an error because your file and your code are not at the same address. Try putting the file and the code at the same address. My file:
C:\Desktop\Files\Python\polarbear.jpg
My code:
C:\Desktop\Files\Python\code.py if you do this solution do not write all of the path just the file name. Example:
"polarbear.jpg" Same thing happend to me also I looked for every solution and I couldnt fix it when I was messing around I found the problem. It realy works

Comment: If you do the solution that I gave do not write the whole adress just write the file name and the type example: "polarbear.jpg"

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it didn't like the '~' symbol used in Mac to route to Documents with '~/Documents' so I changed it to '../../../Documents'